# Fixing a flashlight model

Tags: modeling, normals, topology

This is my first time when I'm making a low-poly model for a game and I have problems already.

I will send screenshots to Imgur because I don't have enough reputation
https://i.stack.imgur.com/n4pKt.jpg

I wanted to make a model of a Maglite flashlight.

Generally I have a problem with that indentation for a button. I tried to use a boolean modifier but topology was very messy.

Then I tried to make that indentation manually. Results in hi-poly model were a lot of better but in low-poly it still was looking very strange. Maybe baking is the answer?

I have also problem with normals. They are in the right direction but still they are looking wrong.

There is also a .blend file https://www.sendspace.com/file/46h8fv

Thank you very much for help.

Comment: Do a little more research on hard surface modeling, this is a rather specific issue that might be better solved by you just learning more general concepts that will help you later on. One tip: You will find that using a good boolean and an `Edge Split` modifier in conjunction helps a lot.

Comment: I was working with hard surface modeling but only with hi-poly models. I tried using an Edge Split modifier and something went wrong but I'll try again. So Edge Split is a solution? There won't be any problems with baking and texturing with splitted edges?

Comment: Ok, I think that I've done everything I could. Can you just please tell me does it look like it should? [Imgur](https://i.imgur.com/BjtHjKD.png) And with normal map and textures it should look better.

Comment: Just so you know, as of 09/2017 you don't need reputation to post images (on this site at least).